# Threading with forms and classes

Tags: c#

I wrote a program to design a web browser. I organized my code into classes. Actually I have several questions...

**First question:**

To access form elements I used this statement in my class:

```
Form1 fc = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
```

when I call an element I use:

```
fc.listboxObject.SelectedItem;
```

I don't know if this is the right way because when I use

```
`Form1 f=new Form1();`
```

it will create new form and it will not update the original one. I set all the elements in the form to public.

**Second question**
In the form I have to create new web page windows using threads so the user can request more than one webpage in different windows.

```
    public void start_new_page()
    {
       Form1 f = new Form1();
       Application.Run(f);

    }

    private void new_page_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start_new_page));
        t.Start();

    }
```

When the button is clicked I get the following error:
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listboxObject' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I searched a lot for solutions I found using invoke and I don't want to use it because it will update the original form only. I want to make each form separated from each other but sharing same history list and favorite list. Also, I can not use Backgroundworker. the following code is one of the methods on one of the classes and I got error here. Actually in all the methods in the classes I face this error.

```
    public void printlistbox(string textname)
    {
        Form1 fc = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["form1"];
        int count = 0;
        string line1;
        System.IO.StreamReader file1 = new System.IO.StreamReader(textname);
        fc.listboxObject.Items.Clear();
        while ((line1 = file1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] split = line1.Split(new Char[] { '\t' });
            count = 0;
            foreach (string s in split)
            {

                if (count == 1)
                    fc.listboxObject.Items.Add(s);
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        file1.Close();
```

When the button print is clicked, printlistbox function will be called.

Comment: There are a couple of things you should never do when you are just starting out learning the language and object-oriented programming.  Using a thread is on the top of that list.  A browser style program never needs it.

Answer (score 0):

When call 'new Form()' you applcation create some elements on the main thread, when calling it on seperate thread you can create a cross operation Try to do this

```
   public void start_new_page()
   {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
              (Action)delegate()
        {
             Form1 f = new Form1();
             Application.Run(f);
        }, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd question is the easiest...  You don't need to manually create new threads here.  This will display a new form which will automatically have its own thread.

```
private void new_page_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 f = new Form1();
   f.Show();
}
```

Comment: I used this before but It is also give me same error:Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listboxObject' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: That's correct.  You can only change controls from its owning thread.  That's what the `Invoke` method on the form object is for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke if you read / write objects on a form from a different thread.

Invoke Example:

```
private void Method1(int i)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { Method1(i); }));
  }
  else
  {
    // Put your code here...
  }
}
```